# How to set font Bold, Italic, and Underlined in Qt?

Tags: qt, text, fonts

I want to make a program that's like a simple text editor using Qt 4.6.2.

When the user block any text in a `TextEdit` and click on a button, the text will be bold/italic/underlined depending on the button..

I'm a beginner in Qt Programming, so if Possible, can you insert the programming code in Qt to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [setFontWeight](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#setFontWeight) for bold, [setFontItalic](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#setFontItalic) for italic and [setFontUnderline](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#setFontUnderline) for underline. These methods set the corresponding attribute of the selected text.